# MongoDB .Net - Filter items in array child

Tags: .net, mongodb

I have a collection in mongo with the documents.

```
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "test1",
    active: true,
    cars: [
       { _id: "2", name: "aaa", active: true },
       { _id: "3", name: "bbb", active: false },
       { _id: "4", name: "ccc", active: true },
},
{
    _id: "2",
    name: "test2",
    active: false,
    cars: [
       { _id: "10", name: "aaa", active: true }
}
```

I would like to return only the active items. In this example:

```
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "test1",
    active: true,
    cars: [
       { _id: "2", name: "aaa", active: true },
       { _id: "4", name: "ccc", active: true },
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregation pipeline to `$filter` the inactive array elements

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match : {"active" : true}},
    {$addFields : {
        cars : {
            $filter : {
                input : "$cars", 
                as : "c", 
                cond : "$$c.active"}
            }
    }}
])
```

result

```
> db.col.aggregate([{$match : {"active" : true}},{$addFields : {cars : {$filter : {input : "$cars", as : "c", cond : "$$c.active"}}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "1",
        "name" : "test1",
        "active" : true,
        "cars" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "2",
                        "name" : "aaa",
                        "active" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "4",
                        "name" : "ccc",
                        "active" : true
                }
        ]
}
```